# Number of neutrons per same weight samples

Tags: atoms, neutrons

I've stumbled on this question that I can't seem to figure the answer of:

> Which of the following 4 samples contains the least number of neutrons,  considering that they all have the same mass.
>
> - sample of C
> - sample of O2
> - sample of H2O
> - sample of CO2

So in order to calculate that I first calculated the number of atoms in sample and found out that the sample of CO2 has the least amount of atoms (1/44 * Na in 1g sample).Following from that I concluded that it also has the least amount of neutrons.

But the correct answer is apparently H2O and I have no idea how to arrive at that answer.

Any help or hints appreciated!

Comment: You don't have "the least _amount_ of neutrons", you have "the least _number_ of neutrons".

Comment: @JEB Thank you. I corrected the mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this problem is to note that comparing the number of neutrons in same-mass samples of these compounds is (roughly, up to binding energy differences) the same as comparing the neutron-to-proton ratio in each compound, which you can find using the atomic weights on the periodic table.

Here, H2O has the lowest neutron-to-proton ratio (and therefore the lowest number of neutrons) because the dominant isotope of hydrogen is protium, which has 1 proton and 0 neutrons. This offsets the neutron-to-proton ratio of H2O enough to make it the lowest out of the rest of the compounds, which all have a ratio of roughly 1:1.

Comment: Yes thank you I get it now. I incorrectly assumed that each compound has 1:1 ratio of neutrons and protons which is clearly not the case for H2O which has 8 neutrons and 10protons so 4/5 ratio.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the approximation that $m_n = m_p = m_N$ (The capital $N$ stands for "Nucleon")
2. Make the approximation that binding energy per nucleon satisfies:  $ E \ll m_N$
3. Make the approximation that $m_e = 0$

Together, that mean the mass of a sample is proportional to the number of nucleons (regardless of their nuclear configuration or $I_3$).

Now: count the fraction of nucleons per molecule.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now. I am just curious tho, what do you mean by $I_3$?

Comment: @Bertoncelj1 $I_3$ is the third component of isospin. Saying "regardless of their $I_3$" is the same as saying "for a fixed number of nucleons,...regardless of what fraction of the number is neutrons and what is protons".